# an object reference is required to access non-static field, member, or property when using inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna-4.0

Hello I'm having some strange problems in Visual Studios C# 2010 Express. I'm trying to have one object inherit from another one but I keep getting the same error.

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PurpleThing.BasicSprite.texture' C:\Users\HAL-9000\Desktop\Examples\PurpleThing\PurpleThing\PurpleThing\AnimateSprite.cs 13  39  PurpleThing

this is the parent class I want the other class to inherit from:

```
    namespace PurpleThing
{
    class BasicSprite
    {
        //Variable Drawing parameters
        protected Texture2D texture;
        protected Color tintColor;
        protected Vector2 spritePosition;

        public BasicSprite(Texture2D texture, Color tintColor)
        {
            //Saving external data into private/protected data
            this.texture = texture;
            this.tintColor = tintColor;
            //Adding a default point to draw the sprite at
            spritePosition = Vector2.Zero;
        }

        public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, spritePosition, tintColor);
        }

        //Number of public outlets for information and remote changes
        public Texture2D Texture
        {
            get { return (texture); }
            set { texture = value; }
        }

        public Vector2 SpritePosition
        {
            get { return (spritePosition); }
            set { spritePosition = value; }
        }

        public Color TintColor
        {
            get { return (tintColor);}
            set { tintColor = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class I want to inherit from the one above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace PurpleThing
{
    class AnimateSprite : BasicSprite
    {

        public AnimateSprite() : base(texture, tintColor)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I'm a very new programmer so this program isn't very complex but I can't figure this problem out. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to pass parameters from your constructor to the base constructor.

But your constructor doesn't actually have any parameters, so `texture` in the derived class doesn't mean anything.

You need to add the parameters to the derived type's constructor.

Comment: @chomba So I need to have a copy of the parent parameter I want to use in the new constructor? Like this? `public AnimateSprite(Texture2D texture, Color tintColor) : base(texture, tintColor)
        {

        }` Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Wolfspaine Yes, constructors are not inherited, so you have to specify what constructor to call in the base class every time a new instance of the derived type is created. You could circumvent the need to that by defining a parameterless constructor in the base class.